# Converting Text to JSON in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, api, text, type-conversion

I have an API sending a JSON to a Postgres endpoint, but due to how the infrastructure is set up, it arrives as text. Can I use to_json() to convert the text back into JSON for manipulation in a Postgres function, or should I set up something to wrap the function so that it converts it and then sends it to a function or stored procedure?

Comment: If the value is  a properly formatted json value, you can just cast it: `'{"foo": 42}'::jsonb`

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!